# ios link website to app to play songs

Tags: ios, web, hyperlink, media

I want my application to be able to play songs that are stored in my website when the play button that I have in my UIview is pressed. I want to know how I can link my application to my website to make this happen.

It someone knows please help, thanks

Comment: I think people are down voting you because it does not appear that you have tried to solve it before asking your question. People like to see effort put into a problem by the person asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just us an `MPMoviePlayerController` and set the content URL to the URL of the song on your website.